# Cannot bind Table headerText

Tags: sapui5

I am looking to bind the data to the table headerText, unfortunately I'm not able to bind to table header data.

Is it possible to bind the data to the Table Header. Header showing nothing "blank",

```
<Table id="BoM"  
  headerText="{oModelBoM>/ItemCateg}"
  class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto"
  items="{path:'oModelBoM>/'}">
```

.js

```
getProductBoM : function(iNumber){
        var sNumber = iNumber.toString();
        while (sNumber.length < 18) {
            sNumber = "0" + sNumber
        }

        // var vUriRead = "/ProductHead2BOM/?$filter=Material%20eq%20'" + sNumber + "'";
        var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('" + sNumber + "')/ProductHead2BOM";
        var oResult;

        this.initODataModel( );


        this.oDataModel.read(vUriRead, null, null, false, function(oData, oResponse) {
            oResult = oData;
        }, function(oError) {
              jQuery.sap.log.error("OData-Error in function getProductBoM (EntityProductHead2BOM)");
              zplm_homepage.zplm_homepage.src.odata.displayRequestFailedMessage(oError);
        });

    return oResult;
```

controller.js

```
onInit : function() {

    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.handleRouteMatched, this);


    this.oModelBoM = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    this.getView().setModel(this.oModelBoM, "oModelBoM");

}

handleRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "ListDetailView") {
        var iNumber = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").number;

var oBoM = zplm_homepage.zplm_homepage.src.odata.getProductBoM(iNumber);

        this.oModelBoM.setData(oBoM.results);
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of this `oModelBoM` that you're trying to bind to the table?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Is it not possible to declare inside elements? can i have example of setHeaderText().

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to bind the collection "/ItemCateg" to the headerText of the table while it expects only a string: [see here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/controlProperties)

So, you can check what is returned in the "/ItemCateg" and fix the issue by binding a property to the headerText and not the array. You can also do that in the controller with a method setHeaderText("someValue");

This [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h35VmCBllaLh4zwhjtHx) shows how to do it.

`this.getView().byId("tableId").setHeaderText("yourValue");`

This link might help you to learn a bit more on aggregation vs property binding in SAPUI5: [binding types SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f0d8ab6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, foremost i am running out of idea. How to declare setHeaderText on controller. would you please help me out here?

Comment: Well url of the plunker is navigating me to SAP documentation.

Comment: i had tried out with simple example like below,

var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
   setHeaderText : "{oModelBoM>/Material}"
  });

Comment: Sorry, I changed the link to the right plunker now. Here the only thing to understand is the value from the "/Material"  path has to be a string"

Comment: i am receiving header context like this "oModelBoM>/Material" as text not binding data. Is it not possible fetch the numeric ?

Comment: You dont have to bind this way. Try this: 

oTable.setHeaderText(this.getView().getModel("oModelBoM").getProperty("/Material")). But First, Can you try by writing to the console what you get the value of the path "/Material"

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: oTable is not defined" this is what i am getting when do in console.

Comment: Could you look into the plunker

Comment: Yes ! I followed steps and referenced to my code. I see no changes.

Comment: Means, when i define .setHeaderText("ABC") it is working, but when i bind property it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: try to log the value of the property in the console and see what you get ?

Comment: console.log(/Brand) and console.log(Brand) i have tried log the value of another property, But no result "Brand is not defined" and "Invalid regular expression: missing /"

Comment: what about this.getView().getModel("oModelBoM").getProperty("/Material")

Comment: i had defined something like this,

onInit : function() {

 this.getView().getModel("oModelBoM").getProperty("/Material")
  
 }
But no output

And also tried like this,
_onTableUpdateFinished: function(oEvent){
      
    this.getView().getModel("oModelBoM").getProperty("/Material");
    
    }
Nothing works

Comment: And my path looks like this var vUriRead = "/ProductHeadSet('" + sNumber + "')/ProductHead2BOM"; 

ProductHeadSet('12345')/ProductHead2BOM later i fetch the property of the BOM with the reference of "12345"

Comment: Any luck on this so far ?

Comment: I had tried something like this,

_onTableUpdateFinished: function(oEvent){
    var oTable = oEvent.getSource().getBinding("items");
    oTable.setHeaderText(this.getView().getProperty("/Material"));
    
    }
Console Error :
Property "/Material" does not exist in Element sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView#__xmlview0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i have found the solution to the above problem. I was not calling an array instead i was binding property name to the header directly.

```
  _onTableUpdateFinished: function(oEvent){

      var sHeaderText = oEvent.getSource().getModel("oModelBoM").getData()[0].BomNumber 
      this.getView().byId("BoM").setHeaderText(sHeaderText );
```

}